# The Battle Between Judah and Sennacherib

Tags: melachim-kings-book-of, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book, book-of-chronicles, king-hezekiah

There is still a great deal of debate regarding Sennacherib's campaign on Judah among historians and biblical scholars.

On the one hand they maintain that Sennacherib did not in fact take Jerusalem but got what he wanted in principle which is Hezekiah's submission by way of tribute, this would be supported by Sennacherib's Annals. Others hold the literal biblical view that the angel of the Lord ended the Assyrian attack by killing 185,000 soldiers.

Wouldn't a crushing defeat by divine intervention have immediate geopolitical repercussions? Had this event escaped outside observers realizing the weakness that Assyria had become? Would Sennacherib's Annals exist in these circumstances of losing 185,000 Assyrians in one night? Apart from the fact that he was killed by his sons much later and not immediately as the biblical accounts suggest, before that he had conducted military campaigns in other regions. Anyway, how should we see this event that seems to contradict historiography, are there Jewish discussions about it in the light of archaeological discoveries and how they support it?

Comment: The biblical account doesn't suggest that he was killed immediately. It just states that after his army was decimated he returned to Ninveh, dwelled there for a time and was then killed. It looks like it was immediate because it took about two verses to tell all of this, as opposed to the siege which spanned a number of chapters. As for the numbers - well, numbers are always tricky. For example, in Sennacherib's prism, he states that he exiled some 200,150 Judeans, which isn't mentioned in the bible. Nowadays researchers think this number was entirely fictitious to make it seem like he won.

Comment: But these details in the prism are not the most important, what he emphasizes is that he locked Hezekiah in Jerusalem and imposed tribute on him, which is to say that he claims a victory in contrast to the Bible which holds that he was completely defeated, this prism being something public at the time would arouse external opposition for declaring it a lie of his making Judah a tributary government. Some historians maintain that a plague of rats in the camp weakened part of the Assyrian army and at the time Sennacherib was focused elsewhere.